# Using RemoteIO gives unreasonable buffers value and sizes

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa

Using the callback function on the iphone , i am trying get microphone input signal.
After so much problems i have discover this :
When i input to the buffer a pure sin wave (to the mac simulator ) i can see the signal, but then, it becomes lower and lower till zero .

I was thinking that this is relate to apple's bug ,that the number of buffer's samples on the mac is 471 instead of 1024 . can i solve this bug somehow ???

This is my callback :

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData)
{


    AudioBuffer buffer;
    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2; //* sizeof(SInt16) ?
    buffer.mData = NULL; 

    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;
    OSStatus status;
    status = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit,
                             ioActionFlags,
                             inTimeStamp,
                             inBusNumber,
                             inNumberFrames,
                             &bufferList);


    int16_t *q = (int16_t *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData;


    //here i print q,which is good for 4 seconds-when i can see the pure sin, than it goes down to zero-while sin wave is still in the air
```

EDIT:

this is not happening on the device, only on the mac !
i am pretty sure its related to the bug that the mac see 417 samples in the buffer !